# How to set Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY? NoInitialContextException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi, websphere-8

I am new to JMS and the Websphere server and I am trying to access a JMS queue configured on Websphere Application Server 8 from my Java code. I am not able to understand exactly what value should be set for Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY. Should it be the fully qualified class name of the class or something specific to the application server?

```
Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:9081");
```

On setting value for Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY as fully qualified class name i.e com.ms.test.Demo I am receiving NoInitialContextException.

PFB the code that I am using -

```
package com.jms.test;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        System.out.println("Start.....");
        Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.jms.test.Demo");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:9081");
       //String pUrl = System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
        //System.out.println("*******"+pUrl+"********");
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(environment);
        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/TestQ111200");
        System.out.println("*** Queue is *** "+queue.toString());
  }}
```

I have made JMS configurations in the Websphere Application Server using the steps given at the link below:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iisinfsv/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.infoservdir.user.doc/topics/t_isd_user_setting_up_jms_in_was.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always use the following, when connecting to WebSphere, not your own class.

```
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
```

It is required to correctly connect to WAS.
For the second property you need to provide bootstrap port not http. Usually it is `2809`, look for the following message in `SystemOut.log`:

```
00000001 NameServerImp A   NMSV0018I: Name server available on bootstrap port 2809.
```

You will also need specific jars for your client to connect to WAS JMS. See
[Installing and configuring the Thin Client for JMS with WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tjj_jmsthcli_dev.html?lang=en)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But where can I find System.out.log?

Comment: Got System.log. Asking this would be silly but how can I test it? I mean it should be run as Java application or Run On Server?

Comment: @Lizzie You should run as Java application, not on server, as if I understood you well you want to access queues in app server from external Java program not application deployed on WAS