# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi, websphere-8

I am trying to access a jms queue configured on Websphere Application Server 8. But I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers Exception.
Can anyone suggest a solution? Does any jar file needs to be added?
I have already added -

```
com.ibm.ws.messagingClient.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.client_ExpeditorDRE_8.0.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.0.0.jar
com.ibm.xml.thinclient_8.0.0.jar
```

in classpath.
You can find the code at [How to set Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY? NoInitialContextException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892729/how-to-set-context-initial-context-factory-noinitialcontextexception)

```
package com.jms.test;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    System.out.println("Start.....");
    Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2810");
    //String pUrl = System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
    //System.out.println("*******"+pUrl+"********");
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(environment);
    Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/inQueue");
    System.out.println("*** Queue is *** "+queue.toString());
}}
```

Exception Stack Trace -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers
at com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:230)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:343)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:281)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:206)
at com.jms.test.Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:646)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar` it is in the `WebSphere\AppServer85\runtimes` folder. `CommonHelpers` class is in that jar.

UPDATE for comment

This might be related to SSL required. Please check these two post how to disable SSL:

- [initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614221)
- [Connecting to JMS queues in WAS8.0 Server](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014934550)

Comment: I am getting another exception now `Exception in thread "P=741213:O=0:CT" javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]`